# How to make child xml node with while loop using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, appendchild

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$root=$xml->createElement("ROOT");
$xml->appendChild($root);

$data=$xml->createElement("DATA");

while($row=db_fetch_object($result))
{
    $data=$xml->createElement("ITEM");
    $item->setAttribute("COMPANY",$row->field_windmill_fabrikant_value);
    $item->setAttribute("HEIGHT",$row->field_windmill_ashoogte_value);
    $item->setAttribute("POWER",$row->field_windmill_vermogen_value);
    $item->setAttribute("LOCATION",$row->field_windmill_provincie_value);
    $item->setAttribute("START_YEAR",$row->field_windmill_startjaar_value);
    $data->appendChild($item);
}

$root->appendChild($data);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Here I want to append ITEM as a child node to data but ITEM is getting appended to item and not to data.  I'm using PHP.
Can anyone help in it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
$data=$xml->createElement("ITEM");
```

with

```
$item=$xml->createElement("ITEM");
```

result of this will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>
    <DATA>
        <ITEM COMPANY="COMPANY0" HEIGHT="HEIGHT0" POWER="POWER0" LOCATION="LOCATION0" START_YEAR="START_YEAR0"/>
        <ITEM COMPANY="COMPANY1" HEIGHT="HEIGHT1" POWER="POWER1" LOCATION="LOCATION1" START_YEAR="START_YEAR1"/>
        <ITEM COMPANY="COMPANY2" HEIGHT="HEIGHT2" POWER="POWER2" LOCATION="LOCATION2" START_YEAR="START_YEAR2"/>
    </DATA>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: But I want ITEM to be appended to the data. If I do this it works 
$item=$xml->createElement("ITEM",""); in while loop. ITEM is appended to ITEM in DATA node. 
Also, I needed help for saving xml file. If I try to save xml file with $xml->saveXML("at.xml"); it throws an error.

Comment: sorry? can't understand what you want. can you please show example of xml you want?

Comment: also - for save file use [`$xml->save('filename');`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php)